# What does "気結び" mean?

Tags: translation, meaning

According to a (non japanese, but he spent lots of time in Japan) Aikido teacher I know, this is supposed to represent "an obligation bounding student and teacher".

To be honest, I am a bit skeptical. I know that this is the starting part of the name of a specific "Kata" in Iwama Style Aikido (see [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dKjGXHrko4k) for an example) but I wonder if there is some other "esoteric" meaning or figure of speech that I am missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did not know the word, but according to web search, I think that 気結び is an Aikido (合気道) terminology to describe the feeling of unity with the teacher, other students, and dojo itself.  気 (*ki* in Aikido) is a word used in Aikido which means something like “spirit.”  結び is the noun form of 結ぶ, which is a verb in daily use and means “to tie together.”

Comment: Thanks! But I am a bit surprised about you saying that 気 or (氣) is an Aikido word. It may not be used much in secular talk but it comes from Chinese philosophy and especially Daoism, and as such it surely predates Aikido by centuries.

Comment: @p.marino: Perhaps you should put these kind details in the question to get the answer you are looking for?

Comment: @Tim? I know what "Ki" means - but I didn't know what 気結び means. I am just surprised to see "ki" labelled as an "Aikido word". And I really don't see what "detail" should add in this case.

Comment: @p.marino: Hmm, maybe calling 気 an Aikido word was misleading.  As you said, this usage does not originate in Aikido.  I edited the answer, which is hopefully better wording.